# Break word in table in Edge

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge, word-wrap, word-break

I have a table like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>http://insertreallylongurlhere</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this css:

```
body {word-break: break-word;}
```

On mobile (or at small screen sizes) on Edge, the long url won't break and overflows off-screen.

It works fine except for in Edge. I know Edge doesn't really like word-break: break-word.

So, I've tried word-wrap: break-word and overflow-wrap: break-word on both the table and on the td. However, it seems like tables don't like that.

If I add table-layout: fixed and a width (such as width: 100%) to my table, the words wrap properly, but the width style breaks my table. It breaks out of my containing div.

Does anyone know another solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `overflow-wrap: break-word;` property, more detail information, please check [the overflow-wrap CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap).

Besides, you could also try to use the `word-break: break-all;` property, instead of `word-break: break-word;`

```
<style>
    body {
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    table td {
        width: 100px;
        word-break:break-all;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>some content</td>
                        <td>http://insertreallylongurlhere</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried the overflow-wrap property. It didn't help in this case. The word-break: break-all worked, but it breaks all the content so that's it's not very readable. Can't have that, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if one word is too long, I think we could only use the break-all property to make it break, otherwise, we need to increase the width property and make it no overflow. For the URL, we could display it using html <a> tag, such as: `<td><a href="http://insertreallylongurlhere">http://insertreallylongurlhere</a></td>`. The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSWmj.png).